# Noding a network with grade separation - open source solution?

Tags: geometric-network

Various network data standards (such as those used by Open Street Map, pgrouting) employ "nodes for junctions, intersections for bridges/tunnels" rule.  That is to say, links are considered disconnected if they merely intersect but joined if they have coincident endpoints.

Other standards use a rule of "nodes wherever links cross", even if there is no node in practice (e.g. bridge, tunnel).  The ambiguity thus caused is resolved by grade separation data.

Is there an open source tool for converting the former into the latter?